# React Native error with WebView

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native

I'm getting an error after authorizing and getting a token from a service and keep getting the following error:

```
    RCTJSLog> "encountered an error loading page",
 {"target":19,"canGoBack":false,"domain":"WebKitErrorDomain","code":102,"loadi

ng":false,"title":"","canGoForward":false,"description":"Frame load 

interrupted","url":""}
```

Any idea what this means? It is skipping the Web View because I have already authenticated but gives me an error screen.

Here is the [GIT](https://github.com/rahul1346/rcapp)

Comment: Where in your code is this being called? Have you tried it outside of React Native (i.e. with curl) with the same parameters to verify it works?

Comment: Man I have the same error. I don't know how can I resolve it. I'm accessing an url that do a 301 to a customSchema://... when the url do it, I receive this error on webview =( I'm going crazy

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug on React Native old version.

you should update your version.

check this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2904